# Freetype available_sizes is null after initializing a face

Tags: c++, freetype, freetype2

After loading a face of a .ttf file, the `num_fixed_sizes` is always 0 and `available_sizes` always **NULL** no matter what .ttf file is given.

```
int main(){
    FT_Library library;

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&library)) {
        // error
    }

    FT_Face face;
    int error = FT_New_Face(library,
                            "path_to_file/alpha.ttf",
                            0,
                            &face);

    if (error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format)
    {
        // error
    }
    else if (error)
    {
        // error
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, everything is set but `num_fixed_sizes` and `available_sizes`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_open_face see the looping over all faces code given under ft_open_face